# Jetpack compose hierarchy awareness

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I created a couple of Chip and Chips @Composable functions that I use like this:

```
    Chips {
        Chip(text = "Apple")
        Chip(text = "Banana")
        Chip(text = "Cherry")
    }
```

I'd like the first and last chip to look a bit different.
I could do it by using extra arguments to the Chip function:

```
    Chips {
        Chip(text = "Apple", isFirst = true)
        Chip(text = "Banana")
        Chip(text = "Cherry", isLast = true)
    }
```

It is a bit cumbersome.
How can I make an individual Chip aware of its siblings.

Similarly we might want to change the color of the Chips depending on whether there are Chips inside or not.

```
    Chips(chipCount = if (addCherry) 3 else 2) {
        Chip(text = "Apple")
        Chip(text = "Banana")
        if (addCherry) Chip(text = "Cherry")    
    }
```

How would I do that more elegantly.

Answer (score 2):

I would send array of chip data into `Chips` composable and then use a loop to add `Chip` composables.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Chips(
    chips: List<ChipData>
) {
    chips.forEachIndexed { index, chip ->
        Chip(
            text = chip.text,
            isFirst = index == 0,
            isLast = index == chips.lastIndex,
        )
    }
}
```

Similarly, you can change the colour of `Chips` based on the size of the list of `Chip` objects.

If you want to pass multiple completely different composables, slotting might as well save you (this is how toolbars and such are done). Instead of an object, you send in a composable, which can then be anything you want (the same was a `Button` is also done). Here is an example of it:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun ListOfComposables() {
    val comps = listOf<@Composable (isFirst: Boolean, isLast: Boolean) -> Unit>(
        { isFirst, isLast -> Chip(text = "first chip", isFirst = isFirst, isLast = isLast) },
        { isFirst, isLast -> Chip(text = "chip2", isFirst = isFirst, isLast = isLast) },
        { _, _ ->
            Button(onClick = { }) {
                Text(text = "Button")
            }
        },
        { isFirst, isLast -> Chip(text = "Chip3", isFirst = isFirst, isLast = isLast) },
        { _, _ -> Text(text = "Random text") },
        { isFirst, isLast -> Chip(text = "last chip", isFirst = isFirst, isLast = isLast) }
    )

    Column {
        comps.forEachIndexed { index, function ->
            function(
                isFirst = index == 0,
                isLast = index == comps.lastIndex
            )
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Chip(
    text: String,
    isFirst: Boolean = false,
    isLast: Boolean = false
) {
    Text(
        text = text,
        color = when {
            isFirst -> Color.Green
            isLast -> Color.Red
            else -> Color.Unspecified
        },
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(Color.LightGray),
    )
}
```

The preview of this code looks like this: [image: preview].

Code is quite ugly, but it gets the point across, I hope.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
My first implementation was using a list. 
And here for this question it does the trick.
But if you have several type of chips or want to allow any Text or composable between the chips, we're back to square one.
Also many component like AppToolbar work with a content like that. I wish I can do the same.

Comment: Well, there's nothing that 'list of objects' approach couldn't solve, I'd say. You just need to get a bit more creative with the objects delivered in order to add occasional "random" composable in between. Maybe a common interface or just a property in `Chip` which tells whether you need to add some other composable after current `Chip`. Depends on what your specific use-case is.

Comment: @PascalGanaye I added another example, this time by sending a list of composables.

Answer (score 0):

I would pass the list in the `Chips` composable, but I will add to the ChipData the uiInfo (a sealed Class or an enum) and then inside the `forEach` loop I would do a when.

Something like this:

```kotlin
    enum class UIInfo {
        FILTER, INVERSE, NORMAL
    }

    data class ChipData(
        val text: String,
        val uiInfo: UIInfo,
    )

    @Composable
    fun Chips(
        chips: List<ChipData>
    ) {
        chips.forEach { chip ->
            Chip(
                text = chip.text,
                uiInfo = chip.uiInfo,
            )
        }
    }
```